# Django custom admin urls not defined

Tags: django, django-admin, django-urls

I am trying to add two URLs to a model admin.

```
class JobTitleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [OccupationTagInline, ]
    model = JobTitle
    search_fields = ['title',]
    list_filter = ['status',]
    actions =['add_to_job_category', 'move_to_job_category' ]

    def add_to_job_category_view(self, request):

        return render_to_response(
            'admin/job_title/select_job_category.html',
            {
                'action': 'add',
                'featured_occupations': Occupation.objects.filter(featured=True),
                'title_ids': array(request.GET['foo'])
                },
            context_instance=RequestContext(request)
            )

    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super(JobTitleAdmin, self).get_urls()
        custom_urls = patterns('',
            url(r'^add_to_job_category/$', self.admin_site.admin_view(self.add_to_job_category_view), name='admin_jobtitle_add_to_cat',),
            url(r'^move_to_job_category/$', self.admin_site.admin_view(self.move_to_job_category_view), name='admin_jobtitle_move_to_cat',)
    )

        return custom_urls + urls
```

I've omitted the views code for simplicity.

These 2 patterns are not defined as I get a 404 if I am trying to access them and thet're not listed in django debud 404 page. Yet the method get_urls is properly called (twice actually, not sure why).

What could be wrong?

Comment: Could we see the rest of the code for accuracy?

Specifically, the two view functions you're using.

Comment: I just did. The other view is pretty much the same. I haven't fully written the view as I can get to it.

Comment: Are you positive you're getting a 404 and not a 500 of some kind? Also, what url are you trying to access them at?

Comment: Note: the custom URL is appended to the parent ModelAdmin URL. For the above example, the URL would be `/admin/app-name/JobTitleAdmin/add_to_job_category/`. This is covered in the Django docs in a little [Note](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_urls). Also, the custom URL will **not** be listed in the Django debug 404 page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this successfully, but I copied the `ModelAdmin.get_urls` `wrap` decorator. Maybe try:

```
from functools import update_wrapper
class JobTitleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [OccupationTagInline, ]
    model = JobTitle
    search_fields = ['title',]
    list_filter = ['status',]
    actions =['add_to_job_category', 'move_to_job_category' ]

    def add_to_job_category_view(self, request):

        return render_to_response(
            'admin/job_title/select_job_category.html',
            {
                'action': 'add',
                'featured_occupations': Occupation.objects.filter(featured=True),
                'title_ids': array(request.GET['foo'])
                },
            context_instance=RequestContext(request)
            )

    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super(JobTitleAdmin, self).get_urls()

        def wrap(view):
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
            return update_wrapper(wrapper, view)

        custom_urls = patterns('',
            url(r'^add_to_job_category/$',
                 wrap(self.add_to_job_category_view),
                 name='admin_jobtitle_add_to_cat',),
            url(r'^move_to_job_category/$',
                 wrap(self.move_to_job_category_view),
                 name='admin_jobtitle_move_to_cat',)
        )

        return custom_urls + urls
```

Comment: Interesting. Is that the exact dsmr code as the 'wrap' director? Anyway, this worked right away. Still not sure why.

Comment: What is dsmr? I'm not exactly sure why this works either. The [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.update_wrapper) say update_wrapper makes the `wrapper` function signature match the `wrapped` function. I guess by directly wrapping your view with `admin_view`, the url resolver expected your method to have the `(self, view, cacheable=False)` argument signature.

Comment: dsmr = writing too fast and not checking my reply.

Comment: I think the `wrap()` hack is a red herring. I was able to get the custom URL to work by following the [example in the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_urls) (tested with v1.8). My view method signature is `admin_jobtitle_add_to_cat(self, request, *args, **kwargs)` (it requires a `pk` kwarg).

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it would appear that you're attempting to add some [action intermediate views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#actions-as-modeladmin-methods) to your `ModelAdmin` class.

This is achieved by putting the function name in the `actions` attribute.  If you're just adding a custom action, there is no need to add a custom url.  Your example could be modified like this:

```
class JobTitleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [OccupationTagInline, ]
    model = JobTitle
    search_fields = ['title',]
    list_filter = ['status',]
    actions =['add_to_job_category', 'move_to_job_category' ]

    def add_to_job_category(self, request, queryset):

        return render_to_response(
            'admin/job_title/select_job_category.html',
            {
                'action': 'add',
                'featured_occupations': Occupation.objects.filter(featured=True),
                'title_ids': array(request.GET['foo'])  # <-- this would probably be changed to use `queryset` function argument
                },
            context_instance=RequestContext(request)
            )
    add_to_job_category.short_description = "Add to job category"
```

The `ModelAdmin` class will know how to call your custom function and add the action to the action drop down.  The intermediate response view `add_to_job_category` would need to know how to take input from the action to determine which items were selected.

If you really want to add a custom url, then your `get_urls()` function appears to be correct.  Note that the urls returned by `get_urls` are with respect to the `admin/<app>/<model>`.

If your app was named `myapp` and your model `JobTitle`, then the url to hit your `add_to_job_category` view would be:

```
http://some.site/admin/myapp/jobtitle/add_to_job_category/
```

Comment: Thanks. The action part is fine and working. The problem is really adding new urls for the extra views.

Comment: For now I added the URLs to the root urls.py file but that's not very clean and not the way it's supposed to be done.

Comment: Can you give a complete example URL which is giving a 404?